# Javascript to WCF - MaxStringContentLength Exception

Tags: wcf

I am using a jQuery/JavaScript client to send in AJAX request to WCF REST service (webHttpEndpoint) and I am getting the following exception...

System.Xml.XmlException: The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.

Here is my system.serviceModel web.config definition...

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                               multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MembershipBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="userHttps">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CommonSvcBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider"
                                    membershipProviderName="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles"
                                roleProviderName="MySqlRoleProvider" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="AuthenticationServiceTypeBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name=""
                          crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="false"
                          helpEnabled="true"
                          automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I have tried adding the following binding.....however it does not take effect...

```
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingDev">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

Can you help ?

Comment: Ten questions and not one accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.....the following needs to be changed in the standardEndPoints

```
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name=""
                      crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="false"
                      helpEnabled="true"
                      automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />       
    </standardEndpoint>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the default values for a binding you need to assign the binding name to the `bindingConfiguration` attribute of the `<endpoint>` element in the `<service>` section, like this:

```
<services>
  <service name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MembershipBinding" contract="MyService.IMyContract" />
  </service>
</services>
```

The `<services>` section goes in the `<system.serviceModel>` section.

I'm not 100% sure this will work for RESTful WCF, but from the research I did it seems like it should.

The important thing to remember is that you have to tell the service what binding to use for a given endpoint, and if you need values for the settings on that binding other than the default values, you need to assign the binding you set up to the endpoint.